# Tor with the newer Firefox "33.0.2"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

Plus using TBB I managed to use Tor through newer versions for Firefox but the last update 33.0.2 doesn't seem to work.

I edited network configuration to be manual proxy pointing socks proxy to 127.0.0.1:9050 using socks5.

But when I check Tor it doesn't work so I disabled Tor from command line and refreshed the page and it loads usually, it said proxy server refuses the connection ?

is it a bug in the new Firefox ?

Comment: I can confirm something similar, but not Tor related. I normally use an SSH tunnel to use my home router as a proxy when necessary to bypass an overly aggressive filter appliance at work (among other things, it blocks IRC, which I used to communicate with open source developers). With the recent update to 33.0.2, Firefox seems to be ignoring my proxy settings... IRC (ChatZilla) doesn't connect, I can't reach my NATed home security camera DVR web interface (which I have previously been able to do when connected by proxy via SSH to my home router) and websites known to be blocked by the work web

Comment: Same problem here. What is wrong with new Firefox versions?

Answer (score 1):

Well,try to edit network configuration to be manual proxy pointing socks proxy to 127.0.0.1:9150 using socks5.